# How can I transform array of arrays into one string in Ruby

Tags: ruby, string, transformation, text-formatting

I have an array of arrays looking like this:

```
arr = [[0,0,0,0,0], [0,0,1,0,0], [0,1,0,1,0], [0,0,1,0,0], [0,0,0,0,0]]
```

and I want to make it look like this:

```
 00000
 00100
 01010
 00100
 00000
```

I tried like this:

```
arr.each {|a| p a.join(',').gsub(',','')}
```

but it outputs it like this:

```
 00000
 00100
 01010
 00100
 00000
```

whith quotes ' " " ' in the begining and the end of each row. I want it to be one single piece that starts with a quote then the rows and in the end - quote. But not quoting every single row.

Comment: which is the difference between outputs?

Comment: instead of one whole string I have 5 seperate generated by the .each

Comment: do you need a single string then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`join` without an argument:

```
arr.each{|el| puts el.join}
```

Comment: This is not what is asked. The title asks to convert the array into one string. I would have downvoted this answer, but since the OP comments this is exactly what they were looking for, and accepted this answer, I will downvote and closevote the question because the acceptance means the question was wrongly stated.

Answer (score 3):

try

```
arr.map {|a| a.join}.join("\n")
```

Comment: The OP asks for each item on its own line; you want `join("\n")`. Also, note that `.join("")` is the same as `.join`.

Answer (score 2):

```
puts arr.map(&:join)
```

Calling [`map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-map) goes through the array (the outer one) and for each entry calls the `join` method; it returns a new array where each entry has been replaced by the result.

The [`join` method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-join) of an array calls `to_s` on each part of an array and concatenates them with an optional separator. Calling `join` with no arguments uses an empty string (no separator).

Calling `puts` on an array prints each entry on its own line.

Or, if you want the final results as a single string with embedded newlines:

```
str = arr.map(&:join).join("\n")
```